# Upload and Download Files on Wordpress through PHP

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, file-upload, download

i'm using wordpress source code to develop a website/blog. I created a form where plus the inputs with data that i insert on the database i have a upload file section. It's here i need suggestions from you people. I would like to have a folder inside my wordpress code and upload the file to that place when processing the data of the form.

To download the files uploaded, would be great to have another section in the wordpress panel (like "media") where the user could go and downloaded the files uploaded previously.

That's what is in my mind but i don't know very well how to do it. So if you guys could help me giving me some lights that would be great. If you think you have better ideas on how to implement this i would like to hear them.

So, resuming, this is what i pretend:
-Upload files on submiting a form to a folder created by me that is inside the template/website code folder;
-List the upload files on a categorie in the wordpress panel so that the administrators can download the files from there;

Answer (score 0):

I use this to upload files with wordpress.
I create a upload.php and put this code, also keep in mind, you need to care about security :)

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
status_header( 200 );
$upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['Filedata']["name"], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['Filedata']["tmp_name"]));
?>
```

Or use this PHP function http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

then other option is to save this files as a custom post then you register this custom post as shown here
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types
and it will appear like Media in wordrpress dashboard

Comment: Constantine but the files upload go to where? To the "media" content or to some specific folder you created?

Comment: it goes to uploads folder and to media also, or in the same way you can use php function move_uploaded_file and chose where you want to put them

Comment: I would like to create a new section in the administration panel of wordpress so that the admin could download the files from there (without have them mixed with media content).

Comment: from what i know they have only register_post_type http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type about registering multiple media libraries i haven't found nothing

Comment: i will see what i can do. Thanks for the replys Constantine, it will help.